# Which one is faster to search an item? Hitting DB or iterating list of values fetched from Db

Tags: java, mysql

In my web application  i have a employee table with employee id,name,designation salary... as attributes which may contain thousands of records in it.. I want to search employee name, so for searching employeename which one will work faster hitting DB every time or create list of employee names once in java bean and iterating it for searching every time... Which one is better..??

Comment: Neither.. Keep a local cache (which BTW can also cause synchronization problems..).

Comment: let's see, what if the list has only one item? what if the list has 1000000 items, what if the DB has no indexes? stupid question.  BTW why don't you try it and see?

Comment: That depends on many many factors (system config, program design, memory, place of record in the table or list, algorithm used to search the list etc etc). For example- if the item you are searching is in the dbms cache it might return faster than a item that comes last in the bean list you created.

Comment: This is a reasonable question badly phrased. Please edit the question to explain better what the parameters are. Otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: The approach is dependent on the actual use case.  How many employees are there?  What percentage of those records do you need?  What columns do you need?  What indexes do you have?  However, the rule of thumb is: a RDBMS's searching and sorting algorithms are way more efficient than your hand-rolled ones.  So you have to save a shedload of network traffic before you will get any benefit.  And don't forget volatility.  In short, build an index on employee name and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is depends in few things..

Hitting the DB is IO action and in case you have specific screen/process that does a lot in specific flow of course it will be better to load list from DB once and use it several times, And this is in case that you can be sure that employees list won't be change in DB by other process/Or it can change and this is not critical for you..

If the screen/process make only few hits to get employees it should be hitting DB.

Remember that Hitting DB a lot of time can also load the DB and cause him to be slow.. He can't handle with infinite number of request.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

By far, even if you have millions of records, it is better to hit the database per request. To enhance this, you can add a key/index on your `name` field in your employee table and the requests will be faster.

In case the data in your employee table doesn't vary that much, you have another option which is using a cache for your employee table. With this, your access to the data will be even faster since it will look up the employee at cache (usually RAM), but this comes with a more complex design and adding policies for your cache data retrieval and setting periods to update the cache data.